# Am new to flutter. When I try to run my flutter project I get this error below when it's compiling

Tags: flutter, android-studio

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1256
- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Index 1 out of bounds for length 1

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2m 55s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: Maybe [this](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/88841) thread can help you? Apparently running `flutter clean` could simply solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Solution :
**Update Android Studio**

Which Will Update the SDK Version and solve your issue .

Then before run

```
flutter clean
flutter pub get 
flutter run
```

Comment: i got this new error after the flutter clean, get and run >>> Warning: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"extension-level"). Expected elements are <{}codename>,<{}layoutlib>,<{}api-level>
Warning: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"base-extension"). Expected elements are <{}codename>,<{}layoutlib>,<{}api-level>
Parameter format not correct -

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use this command:

```
flutter clean && flutter pub get && flutter run
```

Comment: i got this new error after the flutter clean, get and run >>> Warning: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"extension-level"). Expected elements are <{}codename>,<{}layoutlib>,<{}api-level>
Warning: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"base-extension"). Expected elements are <{}codename>,<{}layoutlib>,<{}api-level>
Parameter format not correct -